# gaussian binning of data

Tags: matlab, scaling, gaussian, binning

I just have a simple question of how to do gaussian binning for a data point. Lets say that at X = 100 I detect 5000 electrons but my FWHM is like 4 points. Is it possible in matlab to bin the 5000 electrons with a gaussian centered at X = 100. Like 2500 electrons between X = 99 and X = 101 and 5000 between 95 and 105?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a single measurement at a single point (`X=100`, `e=5000`), and also know the value of the FWHM (`FWHM = 4`).

If this is indeed the case, you can compute the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) `sigma` like so:

```
sigma = FWHM/ 2/sqrt(2*log(2));
```

and you can make bins like so:

```
[N, binCtr] = hist(sigma*randn(e,1) + X, Nbins);
```

where `N` is the amount of electrons in each bin, `binCtr` are the bin centers, `Nbins` is the amount of bins you want to use.

If the number of electrons gets *large*, you could run out of memory. In such cases, it's better to do the same thing but in smaller batches, like so:

```
% Example data
FWHM = 4;
e = 100000;
X = 100;
Nbins = 100;

% your std. dev.
sigma = FWHM/ 2/sqrt(2*log(2));

% Find where to start with the bin edges. That is, find the point 
% where the PDF indicates that at most 1 electron is expected to fall 
f = @(x, mu, sigma) exp(-0.5*((x-mu)/sigma).^2)/sigma/sqrt(2*pi);
g = @(y) quadgk(@(x)f(x,X,sigma), -inf, y)*e - 1; 
h = fzero(g, X-FWHM*3);

% Create initial bin edges
binEdges = [-inf  linspace(h, 2*X-h, Nbins-2)  +inf];

% Bin electrons in batches
c = e;
done = false;
step = 5e3;
Nout = zeros(Nbins,1);
while ~done

    % electrons still to be binned
    c = c - step;

    % Last step
    if c <= 0
        step = c+step;
        c = 0;
        done = true;
    end

    % Bin the next batch
    N = histc(sigma*randn(step,1) + X, binEdges);   
    Nout = Nout + N;

end

% Bin edges must now be re-defined
binEdges =[...
    2*binEdges(2)-binEdges(3),... 
    binEdges(2:end-1),...
    2*binEdges(end-1)-binEdges(end-2)];
```

Comment: i think this sounds like what I want to do. I have an approximate idea of the FWHM and want to bin the electrons in between a boundary at discrete points. I will try this and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: what if the number is really big. Lets say if e = 12345678. My matlab crashes when I try to bin such a large number.